# What DLL is ComboBox_SetCurSel located in?

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

I want to use WinApi function `ComboBox_SetCurSel` in my C# application.

For this purpose I insert following statement:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr ComboBox_SetCurSel(IntPtr hWnd, int index);
```

When I run the program, I get the error

```
EntryPointNotFoundException ComboBox_SetCurSel user32.dll
  Message=Can't find entry point "ComboBox_SetCurSel" in DLL "user32.dll".
```

I suppose that this error is caused by `ComboBox_SetCurSel` being located not in `user32.dll`, but in some other DLL.

If this is correct, to fix this error I need to change `DllImport` declaration.

Question: In what DLL is `ComboBox_SetCurSel` located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not actually a function. It's a macro, from WindowsX.h:

```
#define ComboBox_SetCurSel(hwndCtl, index)          ((int)(DWORD)SNDMSG((hwndCtl), CB_SETCURSEL, (WPARAM)(int)(index), 0L))
```

Where SNDMSG is SendMessage. In other words you should do:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam);

SendMessage(hWnd, 0x14E, (Int32)index, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

See this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb856484(v=vs.85).aspx

It's a macro, not a function.

Answer (score 1):

ComboBox_SetCurSel is macro, you cannot use it in C#. Call SendMessage API with CB_SETCURSEL message: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775899%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

This is SendMessage API declaration: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SendMessage.html